# Delete ghost files with special characters

Tags: files, directory, rm

I have read several ways to delete files with special characters, but none of them works for me in one special folder in my cache system.

I have no idea how the files got there, and why they turned into ghost files.

if i do: "ls -li" in my cache\1\a folder I get the following list (partial screen dump):

---

```
335413265 -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 58734 Jul 30 08:18 1ah17.xml
335413267 -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 63256 Aug  2 22:12 1ah1.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah2.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+cyan12.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+cyan1.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+cyan30.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+cyan31.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+gr%C3%B8n1.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+gr%C3%B8n5.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+gr%C3%B8n6.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+r%C3%B8d1.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+sort2.xml
335413265 -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 58734 Jul 30 08:18 1ah+-+sort3.xml
        ? ?????????? ? ?        ?            ?            ? 1ah+-+sort8.xml
242562822 -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 61613 Aug  2 07:35 1amp+operations+in+c
rimping+tool+number+of+pins%3A+-1.xml
```

---

So I get a lot of files without an inode number. 
If I do a "find" in the folder I get a lot of errors saying that it can't read the ghost files.

How can I get rid of these files and/or the entire folder?

Comment: It indicates a currepted filesystem. Have you tried `rm -rf *.xml`  ?

Comment: That only removed the xml files with inodes (healthy files). Now theres only the ghost files left in the folder

Comment: When I try to remove the folder it tells me that the folder is not empty.

Comment: Have you run **fsck** on that filesystem?

Comment: It's a virtual server with one root filesystem /dev/vzfs ... I can't unmount the filesystem to run the fsck

Comment: @FlemmingChristensen can you run `chmod -R g+x /tmp`  and see if that helps?  Also update the question and show what `ls -ld /tmp`  does?

Comment: I get this: drwxrwxrwt 5 root root 4096 Aug  5 13:40 /tmp

Comment: Filesystem is reiserfs

Comment: So what if you `touch /tmp/newfile` or `mkdir -p /tmp/newdir`  Does this work? Is `/tmp` a seperate partition? `blkid` or `lsblk`

Comment: I have no problem creating files or folders. I have only problem with ghost/corrupted file in 2-3 subfolders in the cachhe folder.

Comment: You say it's a VM and you can't unmount the filesystem. Is that because it's running another important task or because it's a extrnally hosted VM? If it's the latter, then you may be able to raise a ticket with the service provider asking them to reboot and run a filesystem check on it.

Comment: Yes it's a remote RM. Is it possible to tricker a fsck run after reboot with automatic fix of corrupted files and fodlers?

Comment: `touch /forcefsck` and reboot may force a `fsck`.  Also, the `shutdown` command has the `-F` option to force a `fsck`.  If that fails, you'll need to contact your service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows of `?` characters indicate directory entries that don't correspond to a file. This is a sign that your filesystem is damaged. You won't be able to call `rm` to remove these files because the files are not actually there, there's only a dangling label. You need to run a filesystem check and repair ([`fsck`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck)).

Given that this is on your root partition, as [advised by garethTheRed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148486/delete-ghost-files-with-special-characters#comment240985_148486), reboot your system and force an fsck on reboot. There are several ways of forcing an fsck on reboot:

- `touch /forcefsck`
- `tune2fs -C 999999999 /dev/sda1` where `sda1` is the block device containing the filesystem
- Pass the command line option `forcefsck` to the kernel at boot time